# how to insert a custom image as a navigationBarItem in swiftui

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to use an image in my Assets to be a navigation bar Item like this:

```
navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action:{
                        self.presentMap = true
                    }) {
                        Image("map_pin")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 34, height: 34)
                    }
```

I works unfortunately the image is masked by a solid color so I only see the shape.
Is there a simple way to just display the image as is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the modifier `renderingMode(.original)`  This stops the overlay of the solid color blue.

```
Image("map_pin")
    .renderingMode(.original)
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    .frame(width: 34, height: 34)
```

Or you can add the following modifier to your button `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())`

```
Button(action:{
    self.presentMap = true
}) {
    Image("map_pin")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: 34, height: 34)
}.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

Check out this article by Paul Hudson https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-disable-the-overlay-color-for-images-inside-button-and-navigationlink

> The difference is subtle, but important: if you are using a Button
>   inside a List, using .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) will mean that
>   only the space directly around the button’s content can be tapped,
>   whereas if you use .renderingMode(.original) then the whole cell
>   remains tappable